# How to implement marker cluster in android maps v3?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
    import com.google.maps.android.MarkerManager;
    import com.google.maps.android.clustering.algo.Algorithm;
    import com.google.maps.android.clustering.algo.NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm;
    import com.google.maps.android.clustering.algo.PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator;
    import com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.ClusterRenderer;
    import com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer;
```

i am getting a error that maps is undefined. i am following the google guide to set up marker clustering.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: You need to add the dependency `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'` to your `build.gradle`

Comment: Can you post the whole code which deals with the marker clustering?

Comment: i have included com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0 in gradle file

Comment: Yes, you need `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0` but `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'` is also needed as marker clustering is a funcionality of the Google Maps API Utility Library (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/)

Comment: @antonio thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm adding this as the answer for future references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As marker clustering is a funcionality of the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/), you need to add the following dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
```